# Set field value of POJO when constructed using GSON and Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am using the new beta version of Retrofit (2.0.0-beta) and I use the Retrofit-GSON-converter to create a POJO.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Unit {
    @SerializedName("capacity")
    @Expose
    private String capacity;

    @SerializedName("content")
    @Expose
    private String content;

    private String percentage;

   // Getters + Setters
}
```

Now when I use a retrofit call to fetch the model, it parses without error and I get a `List<Units>` where content and capacity is set but percentage is `null`.

What I want is to set the value of `percentage` to be `capacity / content` once the object is constructed such that I do not have to do it manually.

Is this possible to do when using GSON in conjunction with Retrofit?

Comment: why not add the logic of capacity / content under the getter of field percentage ?
    private float capacity;
    private floatcontent;
    public float percentage;

    public float getPercentage(){
       return capacity / content;
       }

Comment: Gee, now I just feel stupid, I don't know why I had not thought of that. Feel free to write up an answer and I'll give you credit for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add the logic of capacity / content under the getter of field percentage ?

```
@SerializedName("capacity")
@Expose
private float capacity;

@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
private float content;

private float percentage;

public float getPercentage(){ 
   return capacity / content; 
}
```

Also, if you notice, give the type of variables capacity and content as floats only, The JSON parser will take care to parse the values into pre declared types of the variable.